# Closing netty connection leaves the connection in TIMED_WAIT

Tags: java, jax-rs, netty

I have the following code to start a netty server:

```
    Application application = ApplicationTypeFactory.getApplication(type);
    resteasyDeployment = new ResteasyDeployment();

    // Explicitly setting the Application should prevent scanning
    resteasyDeployment.setApplication(application);

    // Need to set the provider factory to the default, otherwise the
    // providers we need won't be registered, such as JSON mapping
    resteasyDeployment.setProviderFactory(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());

    netty = new NettyJaxrsServer();

    netty.setHostname(HOST);
    netty.setPort(port);        
    netty.setDeployment(resteasyDeployment);        

    // Some optional extra configuration
    netty.setKeepAlive(true);
    netty.setRootResourcePath("/");
    netty.setSecurityDomain(null);
    netty.setIoWorkerCount(16);
    netty.setExecutorThreadCount(16);

    LOGGER.info("Starting REST server on: " + System.getenv("HOSTNAME") + ", port:" + port);        
    // Start the server
    //("Starting REST server on " + System.getenv("HOSTNAME"));
    netty.start();

    LOGGER.info("Started!");
```

When I do:

```
   netty.stop()
```

It doesn't appear to close the connection:

```
[john@dub-001948-VM01:~/workspace/utf/atf/src/test/resources ]$ netstat    -anp | grep 8888
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.21.88:8888      ::ffff:10.0.21.88:60654     TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.21.88:8888      ::ffff:10.0.21.88:60630     TIME_WAIT   -                    
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.21.88:8888      ::ffff:10.0.21.88:60629     TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.21.88:8888      ::ffff:10.0.21.88:60637     TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.21.88:8888      ::ffff:10.0.21.88:60640     TIME_WAIT   -
```

even after the program exits. In other posts I have read that netty does not close client connections on a stop. How do I shut it down cleanly?

Comment: This is an O/S level behavior, not something wrong Java or Netty.  Sockets hang around for a bit of time after they are closed and it's perfectly fine.  Only a socket left in the LISTENING state would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time_Wait is one of socket state. application can not do anything about it. more information here: http://www.isi.edu/touch/pubs/infocomm99/infocomm99-web/. For a busy server, you could tune some tcp/ip parameter to alleviate its impact.